# No consigo acceder a las filas de mi tabla que creo de forma dinámica

Tags: javascript

Por cada dato que me devuelve `consultaIncidencias` creo un `tr` en la tabla . Necesito coger los atributos del `tr` cuando hace doble click en la fila
Al hacer `document.querySelectorAll("tbody tr")` no me devuelve los `tr` que creo en `procesarDatos`

Este es mi código:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            //Llamamos para recoger todas las incidencias y mostrarlas en pantalla              
            $.get("consultaIncidencias", {}, procesarDatos);
            
            //ponemos a la escucha del doble click
            var filasTabla = document.querySelectorAll("tbody tr");

            alert("longitud-->" + filasTabla.length);
            //cogemos el ENDF del doble click
            for(var i=0 ; i<filasTabla.length; i++)
            {
                alert("doble clck");
                filasTabla[i].addEventListener("dblclick", cogerEdnf, false);
            }
            return false;
        }); 
        
        function cogerEdnf(e){
            alert("valor--> " + e.html() );
        }
        function procesarDatos(respuesta){                      
            $.each(respuesta.incidencias, function( index, value ) {
                    
                $("#contenedor tbody").append ("<tr>  <td>" + value.fechaAlta + "</td> <td>" + value.titulo + "</td>  <td>" + value.descripcion + "</td> <td>" + value.observaciones + "</td> <td>" + value.descripcion2 + "</td>  <td>" + value.idEstados + "</td>  </tr>" );                                                          
            });             
        }
```

Comment: Debes poner el addEventListener en `$("#contenedor tbody").`  (bueno, el dobleclick en jquery mejor, no con addEventListener) y luego, dentro, filtrarlo con el event.target para ver si es una fila, y si lo es actuar en consecuencia.  Es lo que se conoce como delegación de eventos y sirve para que desde el padre, metas lo que metas en sus hijos dinámicamente, se controlen los eventos y se disparen las acciones deseadas.

Comment: Tienes en el código una curiosa mezcla, usando a veces jQuery y a veces no. Quizá esa falta de consistenca te esté causando el problema: ¿tienes más de una tabla en tu documento?

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que tienes un problema es que $.get es asíncrono. La solución es mover ese codigo dentro de la otra función:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            //Llamamos para recoger todas las incidencias y mostrarlas en pantalla              
            $.get("consultaIncidencias", {}, procesarDatos);
            
            
            return false;
        }); 
        
        function cogerEdnf(e){
            alert("valor--> " + e.html() );
        }
        function procesarDatos(respuesta){                      
            $.each(respuesta.incidencias, function( index, value ) {
                    
                $("#contenedor tbody").append ("<tr>  <td>" + value.fechaAlta + "</td> <td>" + value.titulo + "</td>  <td>" + value.descripcion + "</td> <td>" + value.observaciones + "</td> <td>" + value.descripcion2 + "</td>  <td>" + value.idEstados + "</td>  </tr>" );                                                          
            });  

//ponemos a la escucha del doble click
            var filasTabla = document.querySelectorAll("tbody tr");

            alert("longitud-->" + filasTabla.length);
            //cogemos el ENDF del doble click
            for(var i=0 ; i<filasTabla.length; i++)
            {
                alert("doble clck");
                filasTabla[i].addEventListener("dblclick", cogerEdnf, false);
            }           
        }
```

Es algo ineficiente, porque haces 2 iteraciones la primera para crear la fila y la segunda para añadir el evento.

Esto a comentario personal, y porque lo he visto bastante, es que no hay motivos para no usar los eventos de las propiedades `<a oncliclk="algo()" ondblclick="otracosa()" />`. Usando este método te ahorras (una iteración que no es poca cosa) y los típicos problemas de cuando vuelves a agregar filas en forma dinamica, las nuevas filas pueden quedar sin evento. Tampoco habrías tenido este problema. En muchas publicaciones que he leído señalan que las ventajas de addEventListener vs ocupar las propiedades son 3

- Permite asignar múltiples funciones al mismo evento
- Puedes eliminar el EventListner, aunque esto no es tan fácil y en rigor también lo puedes hacer con el otro método
- y tienes el useCapture que te permite cambiar el orden de ejecución del tren de eventos (este quizás es el mejor motivo)

Ahora si se piensa bien el 90% de las veces o más, nunca necesitamos algunos de esos motivos. Como quedaría tu coódigo

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            //Llamamos para recoger todas las incidencias y mostrarlas en pantalla              
            $.get("consultaIncidencias", {}, procesarDatos);
        }); 
        
        function cogerEdnf(e){
            alert("valor--> " + e.html() );
        }
        function procesarDatos(respuesta){                      
            $.each(respuesta.incidencias, function( index, value ) {
                    
               $("#contenedor tbody").append(`<tr ondblclick="cogerEdnf(this)">
                 <td>${value.fechaAlta}</td>
                 <td>${value.titulo}</td>
                 <td>${value.descripcion}</td>
                 <td>${value.observaciones}</td>
                 <td>${value.descripcion2}</td>
                 <td>${value.idEstados}</td>
               </tr>` );                                                          
            });             
        }
```